# Different colors on switch button

Tags: html, css

I have two problems with CSS. Is there a way set different colors for input radio "YES" and "NO"? For example NO with red backgroud and YES with blue background?

How to delete a space between radios?

```
<div class="switch-field">
   <input type="radio" id="resetyes" name="reset" value="YES"/>
   <label for="resetyes">YES</label>
   <input type="radio" id="resetno" name="reset" value="NO"/>
   <label for="resetno">NO</label>
</div>
```

style.css:

```
.switch-field {
    font-family: Helvetica;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.switch-title {
    margin-bottom: 6px;
}
.switch-field input {
    display: none;
}
.switch-field label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 60px;
    background-color: #F2F0F0;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: none;
    padding: 6px 14px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
}
.switch-field label:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.switch-field input:checked + label {
    background-color: #5EA8EE;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
.switch-field label:first-of-type {
    border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
}
.switch-field label:last-of-type {
    border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/t2sof0wd/

Comment: check this http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/examples.html 
and use
off color example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For no space between radios add

```
font-size:0px;
```

to switch-field and for backgrounds add this props

```
#resetyes:checked + label:first-of-type { background-color:green; }
#resetno:checked + label:last-of-type { background-color:red; }
```

[UPDATED FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/t2sof0wd/4/)

Comment: Thank you so much for help!

Answer (score 4):

Just add these css in your code :-

```
.switch-field input[value="YES"] + label {
  background: green;
}

.switch-field input[value="NO"] + label {
  background: red;
}
```

It may help you.

Comment: Thank you so much for help!

Comment: can you make correct these answer if its helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout working snippet below:

```css
.switch-field {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size:0px;
}

.switch-title {
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}

.switch-field input {
  display: none;
}

.switch-field label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  background-color: #F2F0F0;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: none;
  padding: 6px 14px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition:    all 0.1s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition:     all 0.1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition:      all 0.1s ease-in-out;
  transition:         all 0.1s ease-in-out;
}

.switch-field label:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.switch-field input:checked + label {
  background-color: #5EA8EE;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.switch-field label:first-of-type {
  border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
}

.switch-field label:last-of-type {
  border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
}

.switch-field input:checked[value="YES"] + label {
  background-color: green;
}

.switch-field input:checked[value="NO"] + label {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="switch-field">
      <input type="radio" id="resetyes" name="reset" value="YES"/>
      <label for="resetyes">YES</label>
      <input type="radio" id="resetno" name="reset" value="NO"/>
      <label for="resetno">NO</label>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As to your first question, yes, using an attribute selector.

```
.switch-field input[value="YES"] + label {
  background: green;
}
```

```css
.switch-field {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  padding: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.switch-title {
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}

.switch-field input {
  display: none;
}

.switch-field input[value="YES"] + label {
  background: green;
}

.switch-field input[value="NO"] + label {
  background: red;
}

.switch-field label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  background-color: #F2F0F0;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: none;
  padding: 6px 14px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition:    all 0.1s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition:     all 0.1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition:      all 0.1s ease-in-out;
  transition:         all 0.1s ease-in-out;
}

.switch-field label:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.switch-field input:checked + label {
  background-color: #5EA8EE;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.switch-field label:first-of-type {
  border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
}

.switch-field label:last-of-type {
  border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="switch-field">
      <input type="radio" id="resetyes" name="reset" value="YES"/>
      <label for="resetyes">YES</label>
      <input type="radio" id="resetno" name="reset" value="NO"/>
      <label for="resetno">NO</label>
    </div>
```

---

As to your second question, the gap is causeed by whitespace in the HTML which affects inline/inline-block elements.

Solutions for this can be found in this [**SO Question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements)

Answer (score 0):

[This fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t2sof0wd/3/) solves the color problem.

I added classes to the labels:

```
<label class="yes" for="resetyes">YES</label>
...
<label class="no" for="resetno">NO</label>
```

And used those classes to assign colors:

```
.switch-field input + label.yes {
  background-color: blue;
}

.switch-field input + label.no {
  background-color: red;
}
```